# Saving an Array of Data from Input type Text to Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

We will be saving the values of textboxes to the database using CodeIgniter in PHP.

**View**

```
echo form_open('site/addprice');
foreach($query5 as $row5){
    echo '<input type="text" name="artname"value = "'.$row5->articleName.'" style="background-color: #EDEDED; border: 0px;" readonly/>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="supId" value = "'.$row1->supplierId.'" style="display: none; background-color: #EDEDED; border: 0px;" readonly/>';
    echo '&nbsp';
    echo '&nbsp';
    echo '&nbsp';
    echo '&nbsp';
    echo '&nbsp';
    echo "<input type='text' name='price[]' />";
    echo '<br />';
    echo '<br />';
}
$r++; 
echo '<input type="submit" style="margin-left: 210px;" class="but" placeholder="Enter proposed price" required/>';
echo form_close();
echo '</div>';
```

**Controller**

```
function addprice(){
    $this->load->model('site_model');
    $this->site_model->addprice();
}
```

**Model**

However, our code is still not yet finished.

```
function addprice(){
    $item = $this->input->post('artname');
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT itemId FROM items WHERE articleName = '$item'");
    $res = $query->result();
    $row = $res[0];
    $supId = $this->input->post('supId');
    $sql = "UPDATE bac_bs SET price='' WHERE supplierId = '$supId' ";
}
```

Immediate help will be appreciated.

Comment: why do you have `$row1->supplierId` where is `$row1` defined?

Comment: `$r` is not defined and `$r++` is sitting outside the `foreach` loop. Is that correct?

Comment: your post data should be handled in the controller, then passed to the model.

Comment: in your model, theres a query that selects items from the Items table. What are you suppose to do with those results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been waiting on your answers to my comments but it seems you are not there. In any case, I am assuming your `$query5` is a multidimensional array with data. Therefore the keys to each value should suffice to set your arrays. This is how I would structure your **view**:

```
<div>
    <?= form_open('site/addprice') ?>
    <?php foreach ($query5 as $key => $row5) { ?>
        <input type="text" name="bac_bs_info[<?= $key ?>][artname]" value="<?= $row5->articleName ?>" style="background-color: #EDEDED; border: 0px;" readonly/>
        <input type="text" name="bac_bs_info[<?= $key ?>][supId]" value="<?= $row1->supplierId ?>" style="display: none; background-color: #EDEDED; border: 0px;" readonly/>
        &nbsp  &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
        <input type='text' name='bac_bs_info[<?= $key ?>][price]'/>
        <br /><br />
    <?php } ?> 
    <input type="submit" style="margin-left: 210px;" class="but" placeholder="Enter proposed price" required/>';
    <?= form_close() ?>
</div>
```

your **controller** can now receive this information in an array format which you can iterate through and send to your model like so:

```
function addprice() {
    $this->load->model('site_model');
    $bac_bs_info_arr = $this->input->post('bac_bs_info');
    foreach ($bac_bs_info_arr as $data) {
        $this->site_model->model_addprice($data);
    }
}
```

and finally your **model** can handle this information much easier.. although we do not have enough information to help you build your model but to give you a rough idea, this is how I would break it up:

```
function model_addprice($data) {
    $itemInfo = $this->getItemInfoByName($data['artname']); //dont know your plans for this query
    $this->updateBacbsBySupId($data['supId']);
}

function getItemInfoByName($artName) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('items');
    $this->db->where('articleName', $artName);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row();
}

function updateBacbsBySupId($supId) {
    $data = array(
        'price' => ''//left it blank since you did not specify what information should go here
    );

    $this->db->where('supplierId', $supId);
    $this->db->update('bac_bs', $data);
}
```